# Converting mouseover to on scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onscroll

I have a piece of jQuery that works when I have my cursor hovered over the div however I would like to change this so it is trigged "on scroll" instead. Any suggestions??

```
$('.services-item').mouseover(function(){
        $('.services-item').off('mouseover', servicesHoverAction).on('mouseover', servicesHoverAction);
        //servicesHoverAction();
    });
```

Comment: `.mouseover(` --> `.scroll(`. Also note that the `.off()` and then immediate `.on()` calls are entirely redundant, and should not be inside another event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code to this:

```js
$('.services-item').scroll(() => {
        $('.services-item').off('mouseover', servicesHoverAction).on('mouseover', servicesHoverAction);
        //servicesHoverAction();
});
```